# Bargain Finder Max

Tags: sabre

I am trying to implement Bargain Finder Max API in ASP.NET application. For accessing the API we need a token. I tried generating the token using Postman but it always returns 400 (bad request). We have created Base64 string as mentioned in https://developer.sabre.com/docs/rest_apis/session_management/token_create_api/v2/reference-documentation# but still it always returns 400.
Further we tried using the token generated using our default credentials "DEVCENTER:EXT" domain. Using the token generated with these credentials we are getting results but they doesn't seem to be right. The response shows flights which are no longer operational by the Airline.

We have been struggling on this from last 3-4 days but not sure what we are missing.
1.) Do we need some specific LoginID/PassWord/PCC to access Bargain Finder Max API
2.) Or we are not using correct API to get the desired results.

Comment: If you are getting bad request, it is probably missing some parameter. Could you please share what you are sending, (without the credentials)? My guess, you are either missing the Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded or grant_type=client_credentials in the body of the request

Comment: @Giancarlo Thanks for your response. We were providing all the mentioned fields as per documentation. Not sure what was the issue, but it all of a sudden worked when tried on a different rest api client tool. It was failing in Postman (bad request and still not working with postman) and in Chrome extension. Tried with couple of other tools and it worked after struggling for many days.

Comment: Not sure what could have happened, it has always worked for me on Postman, but I've seen a couple of weird behaviors in the past. Still, I think it is the best for testing SOAP and REST :)

Comment: are you doing REST or SOAP?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you need a credential (login/password/iPCC) to be able to generate this token to be used in BFM or any other SABER web service.
In this case, you need to contact the travel agency or Saber commercial contact and request a developer access credential.

- https://developer.sabre.com/user/register
- https://developer.sabre.com/guides/travel-agency
- https://developer.sabre.com/contact/developers_contact